# recovery of a lost chrome session on linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, google-chrome, ubuntu-16.04

I incurred a session crash on chrome for Linux. And unintentionally declined the **"chrome closed unexpectedly restore?"**

I am in need of solutions Would it require reading The chrome SNSS files?

Comment: Interesting, I'm hoping there's a file that wasn't deleted yet, but definitely highlights the importance of careful reading before clicking. Tried looking for deleted files in the chrome folder(s)?

Comment: Although I'm not sure how to get the lost session back, but for future scenarios you could install the extension Session Buddy. It allows you to save sessions and has the ability to remember previous sessions. By default Session Buddy remembers the previous 3 sessions.You could install the extension and see if it will pick up your lost session.

Answer (score 2):

Reading back from backup this directory should restore all your session/settings/bookmarks

```
~/.config/google-chrome/
```

Comment: If you only need the actual session data (tabs and session) then you need the stuff from `~/.config/google-chrome/Default/Sessions`.